# REST API URL parameters not working with apache server

Tags: rest-api, apache

The title pretty much says it all, if I try eg. `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?id=1`, I get all the posts as response. URL parameters are not working as they should. According to the [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/), the server is not configured properly to detect URL parameters. There's a common solution given for nginx servers, but I use apache, so I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re using the wrong endpoint. Look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/). `id` is not one of the parameters for the posts endpoint.

The correct way to retrieve a post with the ID of 1 is:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1
```